# The scanner hasNext() , but can't read with nextLine()

Tags: java, sockets, java.util.scanner

I am trying o make a multithreaded server (so it could be accessed by more users at the same time). I manage to establish a connection between the user and the server, .isConnected() returns true, hasNext() returns true, but the program stops at .nextLine() . Why ?
First part of server:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class Testserver {
    static int nr=0,i;
    String mass;
    boolean ok;
    public static ArrayList<Socket> Connection=new ArrayList<Socket>();
    public static ArrayList<String> Users=new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<Thread> Tests=new ArrayList<Thread>();
    public static JTextField user;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        user=new JTextField("",20);
        Dimension us=user.getPreferredSize();
        user.setBounds(500,350,us.width,us.height);
        f.setTitle("Testserver");
        f.setSize(1200,820);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.add(user);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        try{
            ServerSocket Srv=new ServerSocket(201);
            while(true){
                Socket Sock=Srv.accept();
                nr=Connection.size();
                if(nr<20){
                    Connection.add(Sock);
                    Tests.add(new Thread(new Testserver_run(Sock,nr)));
                    Tests.get(nr).start();
                }
                else{
                    PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(Sock.getOutputStream());
                    ps.println("server full");
                    ps.flush();
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

Second part:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Testserver_run implements Runnable{
    Socket Sock;
    Scanner in;
    PrintWriter out;
    String mass="9";
    int nr=Testserver.nr,id;
    public Testserver_run(Socket S,int idd){
        this.Sock=S;
        this.id=idd;
    }
    public boolean checkconnection() throws IOException{
        Testserver.user.setText("6");
        if(!Sock.isConnected()){
            Testserver.user.setText("7");
            Testserver.Connection.remove(id);
            Testserver.Users.remove(id);
            Testserver.Tests.remove(id);
            return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }
    public void run(){
        Testserver.user.setText("1");
        try{
            in=new Scanner(Sock.getInputStream());
            out=new PrintWriter(Sock.getOutputStream());
            Testserver.user.setText("2");
            try{
                while(checkconnection()){
                    if(in.hasNext()){
                        Testserver.user.setText("5");
                        mass=in.nextLine();
                        Testserver.user.setText(mass);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally{
                Testserver.user.setText("3");
                Sock.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

Client part:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Testuser{
    public static JTextField user;
    public static Socket S;
    public static PrintWriter out;
    public static Scanner in;
    public static String mess;
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception{
//      Testuser Test=new Testuser();
        user=new JTextField("",20);
        Dimension us=user.getPreferredSize();
        user.setBounds(500,350,us.width,us.height);
        user.addKeyListener(new Al1());
        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("Test");
        f.setSize(1200,820);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.add(user);
        f.setFocusable(true);
        try {
            S=new Socket("localhost",201);
            out = new PrintWriter(S.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new Scanner(
                    new InputStreamReader(S.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know localhost");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Cannot open IO");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    public static void send(String mess,PrintWriter out) {
        out.write(mess);
        out.flush();
    }
    public static class Al1 extends KeyAdapter{
        int key;
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            key=e.getKeyCode();
            if(key==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                    mess = user.getText();
                    if(mess.equals("stop")){
                        try{
                            S.close();
                        }catch(Exception exc){

                        }
                    }else{
                        send(mess,out);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You need to use *compatible* pairs depending on your needs: either `hasNext() and next()` or `hasNextLine() and nextLine()`.  Each `line` should be terminated by `line separator` character(s).

Comment: so, I used: public static String eol=new String(System.getProperty("line.separator"));  to get the line separator, and changed the last client line to send(mess+eol,out);   I also changed the hasNext() to hasNextLine(), which returns false for some reason; pls help

Answer (score 1):

> .isConnected() returns true, hasNext() returns true, but the program stops at .nextLine() . Why ?

For a start `isConnected()` only means that the socket *has been connected* at some point in the past.  It doesn't tell you if the connection is *still* viable.

One scenario where `hasNext()` returns `true` but `nextLine()` blocks is when there are characters to be read, but the "end of line" marker has not yet been read.  The `hasNext()` result is telling you that `next()` will give you a token.  It doesn't tell you if `nextLine()` will succeed.  If you want to know that, call `hasNextLine()` ... but beware that *that* will also block waiting for a line.

So, to bring this back to your current problem, I can't see where you are writing end-of-line markers.  On the client side.  Indeed, I can't see where you are explicitly writing any form of inter-token stuff.  If you are going to use `Scanner`, you need to read the javadocs *carefully* and design your "protocol" to match the capabilities of the class.

Comment: so, I used: public static String eol=new String(System.getProperty("line.separator")); to get the line separator, and changed the last client line to send(mess+eol,out); I also changed the hasNext() to hasNextLine(), which returns false for some reason; pls help

Comment: The reason that `hasNextLine()` is **now** returning `false` is that you have reached the end of the stream and there are no more unconsumed characters.  Work with that.